# Show alert message if value not selected in dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I am trying to show alert popup when the user didn't select any value from the dropdown

Here is my html :

```
<div id="reminder" class="popup-layout">
    <form id="reminderForm" method="post">
    <div class="modal followup-modal ui-draggable" id="reminderPopupdrag" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div id="errorInPopup" class="error displayInlineBlock"></div>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">select_followup</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="width100percent">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-1" value="1" class="element full-width verticalAlignMiddle">close_with_reminder</label>                            </td>
                            <td class="textAlignRight">
                                <input type="text" id="reminderdate" name="reminderdate" class="marginRight5 displayNone">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="text" name="reminderText" id="reminderText" value="" class="element displayNone width-full marginTop5" placeholder="add_remark_here">                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-2" value="2" class="element full-width">close_without_reminder</label>                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <select name="reminderclosereason" id="reminderclosereason" class="element displayNone width100percent">
    <option value="0">Select value</option>
    <option value="6">Advertisements</option>
    <option value="4">Another reason:</option>
    <option value="17">Checking  financial terms and conditions</option>
    <option value="16">Company not leasable</option>
    <option value="18">Future potential clients  </option>
    <option value="20">Offer is of vehicle type in which we do not do business</option>
    <option value="12">Open application</option>
    <option value="13">Order</option>
    <option value="10">Other ticket already in progress</option>
    <option value="11">Out of office reply </option>
    <option value="50">Portal, ad removed, payment, offer withdrawn</option>
    <option value="7">SPAM</option>
    <option value="9">Unsubscribe MFO Mailing</option>
    <option value="2">Vehicle/part is sold (indicate order number!)</option>
    <option value="8">Vehicle/part not on stock (is looking for something else)</option>
    <option value="1">Vehicles too expensive</option>
</select>                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" name="send" id="sendPreview" value="Save" class="defaultbutton displayNone">                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And i have tried like this in my js function page:

```
var TICKET = {};

TICKET.preview = {

    init: function () {
        this.bindUI();
    },

    bindUI: function () {
        var self = this;
        $('#send').click(function () {
            self.followupPopup();
        });

        $(document).on('change', 'input[name=reminder]', function () {
            $('#sendPreview').show();

            if ($(this).val() == 1) {

                $('#reminderdate').datetimepicker({
                    showOn: "button",
                    buttonImage:vbdBaseUrl + '/images/calendar.png',
                    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
                    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    controlType: 'select',
                    showWeek: true,
                    firstDay: 1,
                    oneLine : true,
                });

                /**
                 * To display the tomorrows date and time as 8AM by default in datepicker input box.
                 */
                var today = new Date();
                var tomorrow = new Date();
                tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
                tomorrow.setHours(8);
                tomorrow.setMinutes(0);
                $('#reminderdate').datetimepicker('setDate', new Date(tomorrow));
                $('#reminderText').show();
                $('#reminderdate').show();
                $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').show();
                $('#reminderclosereason').hide();
                $('#saveReminder').show();

                return true;
            }

            $('#reminderText').hide();
            $('#reminderdate').hide();
            $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').hide();
            $('#reminderclosereason').show();
            $('#saveReminder').show();

        });

        $('#reminderForm').submit(function() {
            if ('' == $('#reminderclosereason').val() && $('input[name=reminder]:checked').val()!= 1) {
                $('#errorInPopup').html('please select close reason');

                return false;
            }
        });
    },

    followupPopup: function () {
        var request = BAS.ajax;

        request.url = vbdBaseUrl + '/ticket/mail/follow-up';

        request.method = 'POST';

        request.data = {
            ticketId : ticketId
        }

        request.ajaxRequest(function(response) {
            $('#reminderPopup').html(response);
            $('#reminderPopupdrag').draggable();
            $('.popup-dragable').show();
        });
    }

};

$(function () {
    TICKET.preview.init();
});
```

I have tried a lot of solution. but none of the things work in my case.
I haven't understood what wrong in this case. i am trying to check the condition  if dropdown value not selected or drop-down value is 0 I would like to show alert

Can anyone help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `alert();`  and `die();` can't appear on the same line. Two different languages

Comment: ha yes but still if i remove die also i am not getting any alert

Comment: Can you provide the *rendered* html for your `reminderclosereason` drop down please?

Comment: Add `console.log($('#reminderclosereason').val())` to see what the actual val is

Comment: `if (undefined=== $('#reminderclosereason').val())`  try.

Comment: Essentially, it depends on what your `->formSelect` code actually does - which you've not provided here.  It's not part of javascript/jquery which are the only tags provided.  So any answer would be just guess work.

Comment: @freedomn-m updated my question check once

Comment: if (undefined=== $('#reminderclosereason').val()) not working

Comment: @stackuser In your updated code, there is no form to be submitted. So why would it trigger? By changing your jQuery to .change and checking for the select it works perfectly fine (minus die() which is wrong). So it's a problem with your form and the submit, but you haven't attached that...

Comment: console .log i am gettign undefined

Comment: If you're getting `undefined` for `console.log($('#reminderclosereason').val())` then your have a bad selector.

Comment: okay..can you pls check my updated question ..

Comment: @cmprogram has a point that it's possibly an issue with the form - you have `<form id="reminderForm" method="post"><div class="modal followup-modal"` which implies the content is inside a `modal` - if this is the case, you **must** move the `<form>` to *inside* the `<div class="modal`.  When modals are rendered they tend to be extracted from their location and relocated within the html (so they appear as modals...) - as such your `form` becomes completely empty.   Open page, display modal, then enter in console: `console.log($("form").html())` to see what's actually in the form.

Comment: You need to start from basics.  Create an empty page with a drop down and check that your code works (`$(select).val() == 0`) - then add a form and add the check to the `submit` method - *then* add the dialog.  You'll likely find what's causing the issue along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was simple - the alert IS working, it just doesn't come before the default behaviour of submit, which includes a page refresh.

If you prevent the default from happening, you can validate and then decide what to do from there. Attached is a working snippet.

```js
$('#reminderForm').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop your form from submitting.
  if ('0' === $('#reminderclosereason').val()) {
    alert();
    $('#errorInPopup').html('Please select close reason');
    return false;
  } else {
    this.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="reminder" class="popup-layout">
  <form id="reminderForm" method="post">
    <div class="modal followup-modal ui-draggable" id="reminderPopupdrag" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div id="errorInPopup" class="error displayInlineBlock"></div>
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">select_followup</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="width100percent">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-1" value="1" class="element full-width verticalAlignMiddle">close_with_reminder</label> </td>
                  <td class="textAlignRight">
                    <input type="text" id="reminderdate" name="reminderdate" class="marginRight5 displayNone">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="text" name="reminderText" id="reminderText" value="" class="element displayNone width-full marginTop5" placeholder="add_remark_here"> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <label><input type="radio" name="reminder" id="reminder-2" value="2" class="element full-width">close_without_reminder</label> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <select name="reminderclosereason" id="reminderclosereason" class="element displayNone width100percent">
                      <option value="0">Select value</option>
                      <option value="6">Advertisements</option>
                      <option value="4">Another reason:</option>
                      <option value="17">Checking financial terms and conditions</option>
                      <option value="16">Company not leasable</option>
                      <option value="18">Future potential clients </option>
                      <option value="20">Offer is of vehicle type in which we do not do business</option>
                      <option value="12">Open application</option>
                      <option value="13">Order</option>
                      <option value="10">Other ticket already in progress</option>
                      <option value="11">Out of office reply </option>
                      <option value="50">Portal, ad removed, payment, offer withdrawn</option>
                      <option value="7">SPAM</option>
                      <option value="9">Unsubscribe MFO Mailing</option>
                      <option value="2">Vehicle/part is sold (indicate order number!)</option>
                      <option value="8">Vehicle/part not on stock (is looking for something else)</option>
                      <option value="1">Vehicles too expensive</option>
                    </select>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" name="send" id="sendPreview" value="Save" class="defaultbutton displayNone"> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: @stackuser You can try this by clicking "Run code snippet" above these comments.

Comment: yes its working there.but its not working in my application..i didn't get why and all.i am not even getting alert.and its submitting the form

Comment: @stackuser You have tagged the question with JavaScript & jQuery. Are you using any other technologies to implement your code/application?

Comment: yes i am using zend for phtml page and modal popup i am using

Comment: @stackuser Then tag it as such, as you may be getting your issues from there.

Comment: @stackuser No, I want you to TAG it as being implemented via zend, as it appears your error may be derived from there.

Comment: i got the problem..can you please make a chat..i will explain it there

Comment: @stackuser Unfortunately you need at least 20 reputation to talk

Comment: @stackuser Why do you have multiple accounts?

Comment: $('#reminderForm').submit(function(e) {
            alert(); its not even going inside to this..if i did like that i am not getting any alert

Comment: i dont have multiple accounts..thats my colleague account.

Comment: @stackuser That narrows down your issue then. Assuming you have jQuery installed, it's a problem with your form creation in zend. I have no experience in zend, and so would not be able to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, don't forget to Install Jquery :-)

```
 if ($("#reminderclosereason option:selected").val() === "0") {
        console.log("Hi");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#reminderForm').submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       if ($(document).find('#reminderclosereason').val())==0) {
          alert('please select close reason');
          $('#errorInPopup').html('please select close reason');
          return false;
       } 
   });
});
```

Don't forget to import jquery.js before you call this .

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: check my updated question..its not working in my case